# selected option doesn't select using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend, ejs

I'm working on my web appliction using JQuery. My select option menu doesn't print selected option.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', ".class", function() {

    if ($(this).attr("id") == "mySelect")
      $("#mySelect").val($('#mySelect').val());
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect" class="form-control form-control-sm class">
  <option id="mySelectOptionIndex0" value=0 selected> A </option>
  <option id="mySelectOptionIndex1" value=1> B </option>
  <option id="mySelectOptionIndex2" value=2> C </option>
```

My code is working and select correct option but it doesn't print the selected option. Using browser I see that selected attribute is righty added.
I tried using e.preventDefault();, using .prop(selected, true) instead .attr() but without soluton. How can I solve? Thanks

Comment: Firstly, your code gets the value of the select and then sets that same value, which is already set, as the value of the element...? Why? It's entirely redundant code. Also what does this mean: 'it doesn't print the selected option'?

Comment: Default select is 'value="0" ', A. When I click and I choose 'B', my select shows always default value (A in this case). I tried to selected by code but it doesn't work

Comment: But that's how `select` elements work by default. Your JS code is causing the problem for no purpose. Just remove it, and the HTML will work by itself.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what .val() does and when to use it. If you want to print your value, try using  `$("#mySelect").val()` instead of  `$("#mySelect").val(index)`.

Comment: @init can you give a clearer description of exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Your code doesn't print anything. `console.log(index)` will print the selected value.

Comment: What's the point of `if (id == 'mySelect')`? Why don't you just bind the method to the ID instead of the class?

Comment: Note that the `click` event is triggered when the user clicks on the menu, *before* they select a new option. So you'll print the old option, not the one they select. If you want to get the new selected option, use the `change` event.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear code. I solved my problem! When I detect the click event and the code executes the true statement, there were other functions running. One of them changed the selected value option and I always see the same selected value. Thanks for your time

Comment: Glad you got it solved. I'd suggest you delete this question as the issue was caused by some other unrelated code, which was not mentioned in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it to access option value or option html :

```
$(function() {
        $(document).on('change', ".class", function() {
            var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
            
            var selectedText = $(optionSelected).html();
            var valueSelected = this.value;

            console.log(selectedText, valueSelected);
        });
    });
```